# STORED PROCEDURE does not exist

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I create stored procedure from mysql client terminal and everything is OK.
But when I try to call it i get this error message:

> ERROR 1305 (42000): PROCEDURE XXX does not exist

After that i try to create it again without

> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS

statement and I get this:

> ERROR 1304 (42000): PROCEDURE XXX already exists

What's wrong?

****THE PROBLEM WAS THAT MY DATABASE HAVE POINT (.) IN NAME ****

****EXAMPLE: 'site.db' -> THIS IS WRONG NAME OF DATABASE AND MYSQL CAN'T FIND PROCEDURE !!!****

Comment: Since you didn't show the actual code used to call the procedure, or the code used to drop it, it's kind of hard for anybody to help.

Comment: You can't spell "XXX". That's my guess until you show us some actual code :)

Comment: Do you have a client like SQL Developer or Toad to make sure that the stored procedure exits after your call to create it. Are you using scripts from a file to execute your logic or are you typing out the sql commands directly. We ened a few more details before this can be resolved. If you're using script files are your schema owners the same as one my have more access rights than another.

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? I tried escaping my DB name with backticks, but it's still saying that the procedure does not exist.

Comment: As it turns out, it's an issue with my (old) version of MySql: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61078 We're either going to upgrade versions (preferable), or rename the DB, depending on which we feel is a smaller pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you have problems with consistency of your system databases after incorrect upgrade or something like that.
What are results for

```
select * from information_schema.ROUTINES where routine_name = 'xxx'
```

Comment: My query is empty. :(

Answer (score 0):

When you are define procedure using mysql client,
you could using root user (or user A).

Chances are you are using another user to call the store procedure,
let's said user B, it could causing some differences on the privileges

If this is the case, you can grant the access right
To view the current privilege, you can make use of this command

```
show procedure status;
```

Comment: @Faraona For both cases? Please include your store procedure, it could be the problem where is lied